# Unpack an object from a list

Tags: python-docx

i'm triying to parse a bunch of .docx files, using the docx module in python, with this code.

```
folder = selec_folder()
new_location = os.chdir(folder)


#p =os.getcwd()
#p = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(_file_))

#Una lista que guarda los nombres de los archivos con extension .docx
docs = [a for a in os.listdir(new_location) if a.endswith('.docx') and str(a[0]) !='~' ]

#patron regex para buscar lo indicado por el usurio, indicando que se igneren las mayusculas o minusculas
busqueda = re.compile(f'{objetivo}',re.I)
n2 = Document()

#loops para seleccionar cada archivo y luego cada parrafo, para verificar que se encuentre el contenido buscado
for para in  docs:
    print(f'Nombre del documento------------------>{para}')
    doc = Document(para)
    
    print(len(doc.paragraphs))
          
    for i in range(len(doc.paragraphs)):
        
        
        #print(len(doc.paragraphs[i].runs))
        if busqueda.findall(doc.paragraphs[i].text):
            p = doc.paragraphs[i].runs
            print('this is the len of run -----: ',p)
            for i in range(len(p)):
                print(p.runs[i])
                if p.runs[i].bold == True:
                    n2.add_run(p.runs[i].text).bold= True

                elif doc.paragraphs.runs[i].italic == True:
                    n2.add_run(p.runs[i].text).italic= True

                elif doc.paragraphs.runs[i].underline == True:
                    n2.add_run(p.runs[i].text).underline = True
                    

##                elif doc.paragraphs.runs[i].Font.math == True:
##                    n2.add_run(doc.paragraphs..runs[i].text).Font.math = True
##                    
                else:
                    
                    n2.add_run(" ")
                        #for run in doc.paragraphs[i]:
#salva el documento de word            
nuevo_doc.save('Nuevo_documento.docx')
broot = tk.Tk()
broot.destroy()
mensaje = messagebox.showinfo('Proceso concluido','El documento ha sido generado satisfactoriamente')

os.system('start Nuevo_documento.docx')
```

basically, the programs asks the user to input a subject to look in the files, then ask the user to select a folder (or path) to work with, then it opens every .docx file in the folder, and looks every paragraph, until if finds what is looking for, if found, it copies the whole paragraph with the format (bold, italic, underline, etc), but after adding the if block that checks the runs im getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\virlu\Desktop\vdfd\buscaTema1.0.py.py", line 98, in <module>
    print(p.runs[i])
```

i understand that im stracting the objects from a comprehension list, but i can't seem to find a solucition for this, if anyone can held, thanks in advance.
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'runs'

Comment: You need to give the rest of the error. The actual exception is not shown, only it's location.

Comment: Also, I think you mean  `for i in range(len(p.runs)):` rather than `i in range(len(p))`. `p` is a `Paragraph` object which is not a collection and has no length.

Comment: actually i get the lenght of runs and paragraphs, and this is the full error: `this is the len of run -----:  1
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\virlu\Desktop\vdfd\buscaTema1.0.py.py", line 99, in <module>
    print(p.runs[i])
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'runs' `

Comment: Your variable `p` is poorly named: `p = doc.paragraphs[i].runs`. Consider `runs = doc.paragraphs[i].runs` instead. Then the later `p.runs[i]` should just be `runs[i]`.

Comment: you are totally right, i was blind, thanks a lot.